# Angular.js how to search in json array for given path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my angular , i am having one $scope variable as below.

```
$scope.roleList2 = [
        { "roleName" : "User", "roleId" : "role1", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subUser1", "roleId" : "role11", "collapsed" : true, "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subUser2", "roleId" : "role12", "collapsed" : true, "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "subUser2-1", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]},

        { "roleName" : "Admin", "roleId" : "role2", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subAdmin1", "roleId" : "role11", "collapsed" : true, "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subAdmin2", "roleId" : "role12", "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]},

        { "roleName" : "Guest", "roleId" : "role3", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subGuest1", "roleId" : "role11", "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subGuest2", "roleId" : "role12", "collapsed" : true, "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "Banned Area", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subGuest2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "Parent":"Banned Area" ,"children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subGuest2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "Parent":"Banned Area", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]}
      ];
```

I want to first find array for given path

```
Admin>subAdmin2-1
```

and insert

```
{ "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1-3", "roleId" : "role1213", "children" : [] }
```

Please guide, how can achieve this.

Comment: you should also try to post whatever code you have tried first before asking someone to solve it for you

Comment: Frankly speaking, i just had no idea where to start from.

Comment: Can do this with a recursive function that uses `Array#find()`. What is expected result? The object , it's parent, it's index etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty but will work:

```
for (var i=0; i<$scope.roleList2.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.roleList2[i].roleName == "Admin") {
    var subRoles = $scope.roleList2[i].children;
    for (var k=0; k<subRoles.length; k++) {
      if (subRoles[k].roleName == "subAdmin2") {
        var subSubRoles = subRoles[k].children;
        for (var j=0; j<subSubRoles.length; j++) {
          if (subSubRoles[j].roleName == "subAdmin2-1") {
            subSubRoles[j].children.push({ "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1-3", "roleId" : "role1213", "children" : [] });
            console.log(subSubRoles[j]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can try improving with a recursion. And you probably want this to be in a function, so you can call

```
var role = "{ "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1-3", "roleId" : "role1213", "children" : [] }";
$scope.addSubRole(role, "Admin", "subAdmin2-1")
```

Comment: Thanks @faboolous. I will try this and accept the answer if works.